# Why doesnt my xna pixel shader turn this texture blue?

Tags: xna-4.0, hlsl

I have a really simple pixel shader:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 uv : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    return float4(0, 1, 0, 1);
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

I have a texture:

```
        Vector4[] textureData = new Vector4[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                textureData[y * width + x] = new Vector4(1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
        myTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, width, height, false, SurfaceFormat.Vector4);
        myTexture.SetData(textureData);
```

and I draw it with this code:

```
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Texture,
                          BlendState.Additive,
                          SamplerState.PointWrap,
                          DepthStencilState.DepthRead,
                          RasterizerState.CullNone);

        myEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
        spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();
```

I would have figured that by calling .Apply() on the pixel shader that the subsequent spriteBatch.Draw() call would have sent myTexure through my pixel shader. Since the pixel shader function always returns float4(0, 1, 0, 1) I expected the result to have been a green square, but instead it renders a red one, as if the pixel shader is not touching it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to change SpriteSortMode to Immediate and change the pixel shader version from 3 to 2

Answer (score 0):

You're never actually calling `Begin()` on your shader, so it will still be using the default shader.

Also, there is a cleaner way of doing it now. You can pass your effect as a parameter to the `SpriteBatch` begin call, [as detailed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

Comment: Neither Effect not the Pass object's have Begin() methods on them. It looks like now instead of calling Begin() you call .Apply() on the Pass object